# Ubuntu 19.10: no Wayland option. Extended gestures alternatives?

Tags: nvidia, xorg, touchpad, wayland, gestures

I am missing the Wayland sign in option after upgrading to Ubuntu 19.10.

The first issue is that Extended Gestures ONLY works in Wayland sessions. So I went down the path of trying to get Wayland as an option during sign in.

Multiple threads suggested to 1) Install Wayland 2) Ensure KMS was enabled (?) 3) That NVIDIA drivers were to blame.

https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/wayland-not-working-with-nvidia/12740/14

After days of looking into this, I gave up and began to look for Extended Gestures alternatives for Xorg.

[Libinput](https://github.com/bulletmark/libinput-gestures) gestures with xdotool is not smooth, transitions are ugly and is slow and varies in response time.

Anyone have any ideas to either fix the no Wayland option, or for a x11 gestures alternative.

UPDATE:

I was able to get the option for a Wayland session by using the Nouveau drivers rather than Nvidia390. 
[Under Software & Updates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKaJ0.png)

After a reboot I was able to select Wayland sign in option. Unfortunetly this does not fix being able to use nvidia with wayland.

Comment: I think the 18.04 releases would switch from Nvidfa to the Intel i915 driver (in my case) when selecting Wayland, but  19.10 (19.04?) removed that feature, letting the user decide on the video driver, then offering only appropriate logins. You can answer your own queston, since you found the solution (nouveau), and accept it to help others find the answer.